# why c++ rvalue is not immutable

Tags: c++, lvalue, rvalue

Code:

```
void test(int&& a)
{
    a++;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

and execute:

```
test(0);
```

why output 1? Cause I think 0 is rvalue, it could not be changed.

Comment: Move operation typically change the move-from object.

Comment: `a` is an *rvalue reference*, not an *rvalue*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both rvalue references and lvalue references to const can bind to a temporary. The difference is, the former is modifiable, the latter is not.

```
int& i = 0; // invalid
const int& i = 0; // valid
++i; // invalid
int&& i = 0; //valid
++i; // valid;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you bind a non-class, non-array prvalue, such as a numeric literal, to a reference, the reference will actually be bound to a *temporary variable* which is a copy of the original value. That is,

```
int&& a = 0;
```

creates a temporary `int` object with the value zero, and then binds `a` to that.

When you call `test(0)`, the same rule applies, and the reference parameter is bound to a temporary; the temporary is incremented and you get the result 1. Of course you are not incrementing 0 itself.

Comment: I know the 0 value was copied to test function's stack. My question is why && operator could change reference's value. And @remyable has answered it. Thanks.